# MFC- receiving Button-Click-Message failed

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I've created a new dialog in my MFC dialog based application. the new dialog contains 5 control     buttons.

the following happens and I don't understand why?

1. click on buttonX. (result ok, OnBnClicked message is sent)
2. click on on any place of the application, but not on the dialog.(removing focus from dialog)
3. click again on buttonX (FAILED, OnBnClicked message is NOT sent). but if instead I click on     any other button in the dialog (result ok, OnBnClicked message is sent).

and when I do:

1. ...
2. ...
3. click on the dialog area just to set focus on the dialog again
4. click again on buttonX. (result ok, OnBnClicked message is sent)

**I need to do step 3 only if I want to click again on the buttonX! why??
I think it related to SetFocus() but I m not sure how.

the buttons IDC are:
IDC_BACK_MEDIA_PRESS_BUTTON 1180 
IDC_TOOLS_LEFT_RIGHT        1024
IDC_MEDIA_FOREWARD_BUTTON   1103
IDC_MEDIA_BACKWARD_BUTTON   1104
IDC_TOOLS_HOOD_BUTTON       2346

the dialog properties is:

IDD_TOOLS_DIALOG DIALOGEX 0, 0, 51, 218
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Tools"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    PUSHBUTTON      "Media &Foreward",IDC_MEDIA_FOREWARD_BUTTON,7,79,37,36,BS_MULTILINE
    PUSHBUTTON      "&Media &BackWard",IDC_MEDIA_BACKWARD_BUTTON,7,43,37,36,BS_MULTILINE
    PUSHBUTTON      "Back Media Press",IDC_BACK_MEDIA_PRESS_BUTTON,7,127,37,36,BS_MULTILINE | NOT WS_VISIBLE
    PUSHBUTTON      "Hood",IDC_TOOLS_HOOD_BUTTON,7,7,37,36
    PUSHBUTTON      "Left Right",IDC_TOOLS_LEFT_RIGHT,7,175,37,36
END

I've tried different style like, tool windows, overlapped, popup. it happens in all the cases.

Thanks for the help.

.h

```
class CToolsDlg : public CBDialog
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CToolsDlg)

public:
    CToolsDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // standard constructor
    virtual ~CToolsDlg();
    CToolTipCtrl m_ToolsTips;

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_TOOLS_DIALOG };

protected:
    virtual void OnCancel();
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    CMFCButton m_HoodButton;
    CMFCButton m_MediaForewardButton;
    CMFCButton m_MediaBackwardButton;
    CMFCButton m_LeftRightButton;
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
    virtual BOOL PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg);

    afx_msg void OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent);
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedCancel();
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedToolsHoodButton();
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedMediaForewardButton();
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedMediaBackwardButton();
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedLeftRightButton();
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedBackMediaPressButton();
};
```

.cpp

```
IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CToolsDlg, CBDialog)

CToolsDlg::CToolsDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
: CBDialog(CToolsDlg::IDD, pParent)
{

}
CToolsDlg::~CToolsDlg()
{
}
void CToolsDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CBDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_TOOLS_HOOD_BUTTON,     m_HoodButton);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_MEDIA_FOREWARD_BUTTON, m_MediaForewardButton);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_MEDIA_BACKWARD_BUTTON, m_MediaBackwardButton);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_TOOLS_LEFT_RIGHT,      m_LeftRightButton);
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CToolsDlg, CBDialog)
    ON_WM_CLOSE()
    ON_WM_DESTROY()
    ON_WM_TIMER()
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_TOOLS_HOOD_BUTTON, &CToolsDlg::OnBnClickedToolsHoodButton)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_MEDIA_FOREWARD_BUTTON, &CToolsDlg::OnBnClickedMediaForewardButton)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_MEDIA_BACKWARD_BUTTON, &CToolsDlg::OnBnClickedMediaBackwardButton)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_TOOLS_LEFT_RIGHT, &CToolsDlg::OnBnClickedLeftRightButton)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BACK_MEDIA_PRESS_BUTTON, &CToolsDlg::OnBnClickedBackMediaPressButton)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CToolsDlg message handlers

BOOL CToolsDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CBDialog::OnInitDialog();

    // Window position
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    CMainFrame* mf =  (CMainFrame*)AfxGetMainWnd();
    RECT MFwinRect;
    RECT ThiswinRect;
    CWnd* fv = mf->m_wndSplitter.GetView( mf->m_wndSplitter.GetCurrentViewIndex(0,0) );
    fv->GetWindowRect(&MFwinRect);
    GetWindowRect(&ThiswinRect);
    MoveWindow(
        MFwinRect.right - (ThiswinRect.right - ThiswinRect.left) - 14,  // X
        MFwinRect.top + 14,                                             // Y
        (ThiswinRect.right - ThiswinRect.left),                         // nWidth
        (ThiswinRect.bottom - ThiswinRect.top) );                       // nHeight

    // Set controls state
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    m_ToolsTips.Create(this);
    m_ToolsTips.AddTool(&m_HoodButton,          TOOLTIP_HOOD_BUTTON);
    m_ToolsTips.AddTool(&m_MediaForewardButton, TOOLTIP_MEDIA_FOREWARD_BUTTON);
    m_ToolsTips.AddTool(&m_MediaBackwardButton, TOOLTIP_MEDIA_BACKWARD_BUTTON);
    m_ToolsTips.AddTool(&m_LeftRightButton,     TOOLTIP_LEFT_RIGHT_BUTTON);
    m_ToolsTips.SetDelayTime(1000);
    m_ToolsTips.Activate(BARAK_PREFS->m_Params.m_bShowToolTips);

    // Main timer loop (no need for now)
    // SetTimer( 1, 1000, NULL );
    return TRUE;
}

BOOL CToolsDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    m_ToolsTips.RelayEvent(pMsg);

    return CBDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}

void CToolsDlg::OnCancel()
{
    // When closing the window, destroy it and not only hide (its a floating window).
    DestroyWindow();
}

void CToolsDlg::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{
    CBDialog::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
}

void CToolsDlg::OnBnClickedToolsHoodButton()
{
    ...
}

void CToolsDlg::OnBnClickedMediaForewardButton()
{
    ...
}

void CToolsDlg::OnBnClickedMediaBackwardButton()
{   
    ...
}

void CToolsDlg::OnBnClickedLeftRightButton()
{
    ...
}

void CToolsDlg::OnBnClickedBackMediaPressButton()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with this code. The only interesting thing is that you say you have 5 buttons when there are only 4 in the code.

Comment: Can you post the numbers behind the IDC - constants please? Sometime I had unexplainable issues, when these automatically generated number are somewhere in a region of system values. Just an idea.....

Comment: What buttons fail? And, try using Spy++ to determine who is processing the button click.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I will edit my question again

Comment: The IDC of all the buttons:

IDC_TOOLS_LEFT_RIGHT            1024
IDC_BACK_MEDIA_PRESS_BUTTON     1180
IDC_MEDIA_FOREWARD_BUTTON       1103
IDC_MEDIA_BACKWARD_BUTTON       1104
IDC_TOOLS_HOOD_BUTTON           2346

Comment: @user3455965: update your question instead of posting complementary informarion as a comment.

Comment: What is `CBDialog` ?

Comment: Does it also fail when commenting out the m_ToolsTips.RelayEvent(..) in PreTranslateMsg ?

Comment: Hey Albi, commenting out the m_ToolsTips.RelayEvent(..) not affect the problem.

Comment: comment the line `m_ToolsTips.RelayEvent(pMsg);` in PreTranslate and see if it still happens. It could be the tooltip.

Comment: Hey Albi, It didnt works. Thanks

Comment: If your application does not have the input focus when you click the button, then Windows may first activate your app and eat the click to prevent accidental button presses.

Comment: I've found the exact click order that cause the behavioral.
I'm adding the information the the question.
thanks

Comment: Have you tried spy++?

Comment: I m not familiar with Spy++. I tried it yesterday and sort only the buttons event. the result window was not clear to me, so i need first to learn how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are filling view with dialog content. Have you put focusing to your dialog? I think this mystic behavior happening only on first mouse click in your dialog (then dialog gets the focus). I'm just guessing :)

Comment: Just hit this myself. First click on a CMFCButton control when it is not in focus is ignored. My code was already using sub class of the CMFCButton class. Solved it by adding a SetFocus to the OnLButtonDown message handler. Could not find any documentation about this button focus notification issue.